# ASP.NET allowable Actions naming?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view that can be accessed three ways:

**1. Empty form - initial get from a menu**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetMe()
```

**2. Populated form after a form submit (after a dropdown value is selected)**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetMe(int firstDropdownValue)
```

**3. Populated after a request from another page via javascript. This is a GET.**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetMe(int secondDropdownValue, int thirdDropdownValue)
```

The problem is that #3 conflicts with #1 because two gets to the same ActionName are not allowed.  I could give #3 a different action name, but I would really like both to display the same name in the URL.

I have looked at the [ActionName] attribute but I don't think it can help me.  Is there a workaround?

Comment: Your example won't compile. #2 and #3 have the same method signature.

Comment: I have edited #3 to make the signature different. The parameters aren't really important here.

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew Barber is right. Forget about MVC for a second, you can't have two methods with the same signature. They can be combined to one.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetMe() 

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("GetMe")]
public ActionResult GetMeHttpPost(int dropDownValue)
```

This of course means you need to change your 3rd option (the JS) to do a POST instead of a GET. If that's a problem, you'll need a third action with a seperate URL.

Although i don't envision a scenario where JavaScript is required to "GET" an entire page - shouldn't it be a child action returning PartialViewResult?

Answer (score 0):

After you fix the compile error, you can combine #1 and #3 with a nullable int.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetMe(int? dropDownValue)
```